# Is it fine to develop cms in OpenCMS with Struts2?

Tags: java, content-management-system, opencms

I have no deep idea about OpenCMS and i want to start my project in OpenCMS.I know Struts2 java framework. I am trying to build CMS in java only.

My question is,

**Should I choose OpenCMS as am developing CMS first time and want it in java AND
Second one is, Can i built it in Struts2 ?**

Thank you. . . . :)

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a project in which we integrated OpenCms and Struts2 in this way:

- Struts2 used as Controller
- OpenCms used as View (engine)

In short: all the request were intercepted by struts filter, and then (after business logic completed) forward to OpenCms servlet to render the view.

Hope this clarify a little bit.